# Tomorrowland movie and tachyons?

Tags: special-relativity, faster-than-light, causality, time-travel, tachyon

Would be possible if tachyonic existed to send info to the past or see the future? since the tachyons according to special relativity could travel to the past?

i have searched in wikipedia and the most accurate info was this link

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyonic_antitelephone

if so could we use the spin of tachyons to send bits of information to the past? :D

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately (or fortunately, depending on your viewpoint) we cannot use tachyons for signalling to the past. I suggest the following as reading:

[The Physics SE Question "Do Tachyons Move Faster than Light" and its answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/166095/do-tachyons-move-faster-than-light)

[My answer to the Physics SE question "Would a tachyon be able to escape a black hole?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/209410/26076)

Basically, for the consideration of faster-than-light signalling questions, tachyons are very like light in optical mediums in anomalous dispersion frequency bands where the phase velocity of the light can be greater than $c$. A monochromatic wavetrain with a greater-than-$c$ phas velocity has infinite length (like any monochromatic wavetrain), so it is meaningless to talk about signalling with such a thing. When you try to build localized signalling pulses from superpositions of faster-than-$c$ phase velocity sinusoidal waves the pulse travel / spreading speed is always $c$ or less.