# What does it mean that the vacuum is unstable?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, klein-gordon-equation, stability, tachyon

This book I'm reading states that the Klein-Gordon equation, for $m^2<0$ has an "unstable" vacuum $\phi=0$. It's talking about tachyons and how their presence is a sign of instability.
What does this mean? How can I see this?

It also says that the model can be stabilized by adding a term proportional to $\phi^4$ but this is just as incomprehensible to me.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/166095/2451