# Can Higgs particles move faster than the speed of light in the high energy (temperature) regime?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, standard-model, higgs, faster-than-light

In the standard model, Higgs particles have negative mass squared term in the SM lagrangian and hence, the Higgs is tachyonic in nature. This isn't a problem since -at low energy (temperature)- the Higgs particle will stay close to the local minima of the the Mexican hat potential and by doing so, it breaks $SU(2)$ gauge and acquires a non-negative real mass. But if we consider the high energy situation (assuming that the energy regime is higher than the unstable maximum of the higgs potential), the gauge symmetry should be restored and - as far as I understand - the higgs should have an imaginary mass.

Can Higgs particles move faster than light if the temperature/energy is high enough?

Comment: A tachyonic field represents an instability, and does not have modes that superluminally; see, eg, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyonic_field

Comment: As far as I understand, the instability leads to phase transition and at zero temperature, we have real mass. But if the temperature is above the critical temperature, shouldn't the system retain its imaginary mass?

Comment: What matters is the *effective* mass squared parameter, which has a negative contribution from the intrinsic potential energy, and a positive contribution from thermal fluctuations. At high temperatures, the thermal contribution is larger than the intrinsic potential energy contribution, and the effective mass squared is positive. As the temperature decreases, the thermal contribution becomes smaller, until the negative potential energy term dominates. At that point, you get the tachyonic instability described in the article I linked above.

Comment: oh, I see. This makes sense. Thank you. By the way, do you have a reference on this topic?

Comment: This is a pretty broad topic. A good starting point is to learn about Ginzburg-Landau theory, see eg Section 1.3 of [Tong's statistical field theory notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/sft/one.pdf). His course page and the beginning of his notes contain some other recommended sources. If you want to know about thermal corrections to quantum field theory, [this review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.01554) looks good (I haven't read it though). If you want to know about the electroweak phase transition, here's a review: https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.12614 (see Section 2.3.2)

Comment: It seems to me you are mixing up the concept of the Higgs **field** with the concept of **particle** . The Higgs particle is the particle sought  at LHC to validate the standard model's Higgs field.. As the electron is the particle generated on the electron field.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Do tachyons move faster than light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/166095/2451)

Answer (score 0):

> Can Higgs particles move faster than light if the temperature/energy is high enough?

No.